# Can't change box-ordinal-group CSS property with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is update the box-ordinal-group property of a specific element to change its order in the page but it doesn't work somehow. My first thought was "is it read only?" but couldn't find anything to support that thought on w3.org. So, any idea?

You can see and test my approach below;

```js
function get_random_int(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var button = $("#btn");

button.on('click', function(){
    var rand_order = get_random_int(1,4);
    var el = $("#blockA");
    console.log(rand_order);
    el.css("-webkit-box-ordinal-group", rand_order);
    el.css("-mox-box-ordinal-group", rand_order);
    el.css("box-ordinal-group", rand_order);
    console.log(el.css("-webkit-box-ordinal-group"));
});
```

```css
#blockContainer > div {
    border: 1px dashed #f0f
}

#blockContainer {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
}
#blockA {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
    order: 2
}
#blockB {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
    order: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blockContainer">
    <div id="blockA">Block A</div>
    <div id="blockB">Block B</div>
    <div id="blockC">Block C</div>
</div>

<button id="btn">test</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to set the values to an integer number. you need to cast it to string and it will work:

```js
function get_random_int(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
$(function() {
  var button1 = $("#btn");
  button1.on('click', function() {
    var rand_order = get_random_int(1, 4);
    var el = $("#blockA");
    console.log(rand_order);
    el.css("-webkit-box-ordinal-group", rand_order.toString());
    el.css("-mox-box-ordinal-group", rand_order.toString());
    el.css("box-ordinal-group", rand_order.toString());
    console.log(el.css("-webkit-box-ordinal-group"));
  });
});
```

```css
#blockContainer > div {
  border: 1px dashed #f0f;
}
#blockContainer {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
}
#blockA {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  box-ordinal-group: 2;
  order: 2;
}
#blockB {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  box-ordinal-group: 1;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blockContainer">
  <div id="blockA">Block A</div>
  <div id="blockB">Block B</div>
  <div id="blockC">Block C</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
$('element').css'cssText', 'box-ordinal-group:<number>');
```

This would add an inline style attribute to the element and add the specified css attributes. Hope this helps.